# Regarding Scala Futures being eager

Tags: scala, functional-programming, future

I have been trying to understand why Scala Futures are regarded as eager and violate referential transparency. I think I understand this part reasonably. However, I have trouble understanding what this means:

`(A => Unit) => Unit`

With respect to a Future.

I am not sure if this is the right forum, but  ELI5 answers appreciated

Comment: I am pretty sure you are referring to [this table](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/datatypes/io.html#on-referential-transparency-and-lazy-evaluation). My interpretation is: _A `Future[A]`, is like a **function**, which receives another **function** `A => Unit` (which is basically the callback to execute when the future completes) and returns `Unit` - Then, `IO[A]` is basically a zero args **function** that returns exactly the same thing_.

Comment: In general this is a continuation, i. e. it is a partially applied function that already has  a value of type `A` in scope. Since the continuation always retunrs a unit, there must be an additional effect to render it useful.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I think I understand things a little better now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why `Future` is regarded as eager (and as such violates referential transparency) is because it evaluates as soon as the value is defined. Below is the ELI5 and non-ELI5 explanation for this.

As for `(A => Unit) => Unit`, it's a signature for the callback-driven asynchronous computation. In a synchronous computation, you evaluate the `Future[A]` to `A`, even if it means sitting in place and waiting a long time for the evaluation to finish. But with asynchronous computation, you don't sit and wait; instead, you pass a function of type `A => Unit`, and you immediately get the `Unit` back. Later, when the computation has finished in the background and value `A` has been produced, function `A => Unit` will be applied to it. So basically you tell the Future "once you obtain A, here's what I want you to do with it", and it responds "OK, will do, here's a Unit for you, leave now and do other stuff".

TBH I wouldn't overthink this signature too much because that's not what your mental model of working with `Future` should be. Instead, just become familiar with the notion of mapping and flatMapping. When you have a value wrapped in a `Future`, you shouldn't try to get that value out of the Future context because that would be a blocking synchronous operation. But what you can do is map over it and say "alright Future, I don't need this value A right now, I just want to describe a function A => B to you which turns it to another value B, and you make sure to apply it to once you have the original A". And if B is wrapped in a yet another `Future`, meaning your function is not `A => B` but `A => Future[B]`, instead of mapping you should use flatMap. This is how you chain asynchronous operations. Imagine a database query which as a parameter needs something returned in the previous query.

And that's it. Somewhere at the end of the world, e.g. when you're done processing an http request and are ready to send some response payload over the wire, you will finally unwrap that future in a synchronous way (you can't send a payload if you don't know what to put in it).

Now, about referential transparency in `Future`:

**ELI5:**

Imagine you have two daughters, Anna and Betty. You tell them that their task will be to count to 20 out loud. You also tell them that Betty should start only after Anna is done. Whole process is hence expected to take about 40 seconds.

But if they evaluate their task eagerly (like `Future` does), as soon as you explain the task to them, they will each start counting right away. Whole process will hence last about 20 seconds.

In the context of programming, referential transparency says that you should always be able to replace (pseudocode):

```
// imagine >> as a pipe operator which starts the next function
// only after previous one has terminated

count(20) >> count(20)
```

with

```
anna = count(20)
betty = count(20)
anna >> betty
```

but that's not true in this situation because of eager evaluation (the girls start counting as soon as their task is explained to them, so in the second case the program will last only 20 seconds regardless of the pipe).

**non-ELI5:**

Let's prepare an execution context for `Future` and a function that will be evaluated. It simply sleeps for two seconds before printing "hi".

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def f = {
  Thread.sleep(2000)
  println("hi")
}
```

Let's now write a for comprehension which will create two `Future`s one after another:

```
val done = for {
  f1 <- Future(f)
  f2 <- Future(f)
} yield (f1, f2)

import scala.concurrent.duration._
Await.result(done, 5000 millis)
```

As expected, after two seconds we'll get the first "hi" (from `f1`), and after additional two seconds we'll get the second "hi" (from `f2`).

Now let's do a small modification; we will first define two `Future` values, and then we'll use those in the for comprehension:

```
val future1 = Future(f)
val future2 = Future(f)

val done = for {
  f1 <- future1
  f2 <- future2
} yield (f1, f2)

import scala.concurrent.duration._
Await.result(done, 5000 millis)
```

What happens this time is that after approximately two seconds you get two *simultaneous* "hi" printouts. This is because both `future1` and `future2` started getting evaluated as soon as they were defined. By the time they got chained in the for comprehension, they were already running alongside each other on the given execution context.

This is why referential transparency is broken; normally you should be able to replace:

```
doStuff(foo)
```

with

```
val f = foo
doStuff(f)
```

without having any consequence on the behaviour of the program, but in the case of `Future`, as you can see above, that's not the case.